# Каков алгоритм поиска утечек памяти в WPF-приложении?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, утечка-памяти

Разрабатываю проект **WPF**, работающий с базой данных посредством **EF6**.
В базе порядка *12*-ти таблиц, в каждой от *100 до 50000* записей. Данные из контекста получаю с использованием конструкции `using(...)`, т.е. контекст "диспоузится" после каждого запроса к базе. Тем не менее, с выполнением каждой команды **WPF**-приложения, так или иначе связанной с запросами к БД, *process memory* вырастает на *30-40* мегабайт. После запуска приложение занимает порядка *120* мегабайт. 
Видимо, где-то проиходит утечка памяти? 
В какую сторону смотреть и что использовать, чтобы её найти?

Comment: 1) Нету никаких особенных методов контроля утечек памяти, специфичных для WPF. Контролируйте как обычно — при помощи memory profiler'а, разумеется. 2) Об утечке можно беспокоиться, если память возрастает до вылета по `OutOfMemory`. Сборщик мусора вовсе не обязан подчищать всё _немедленно_.

Comment: @VladD, дело в том, что я пишу проект на машине с 16GB RAM, а использоваться оно будет с максимум 2 GB. Это меня и смущает.

Comment: Ну, вот вы и оттестируйте в реальных условиях. Вы ж не знаете, как поведёт себя программа на клиентской машине? Без теста и не узнаете.